# Angular2 Form-validation with prefilled data

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I have a form with two input fields (text). Creating from scratch (= no information) works great. As you can guess, maybe I want to change the values later.

The problem: When only changing the description for example (and leaving the title as is from the server), the title will be invalid. If I change the last char (Testproject to Testproject2) for example it works. What do I have to change?

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="projectEditForm" novalidate>
    <div [formGroup]="projectEditForm">

        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" [class.validationError]="projectEditForm.controls.Title.invalid && (projectEditForm.controls.Title.dirty || submitted)"
                   value="{{ (project | async)?.ProjectName }}" formControlName="Title">

        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea [class.validationError]="projectEditForm.controls.Description.invalid && (projectEditForm.controls.Description.dirty || submitted)"
                   value="{{ (project | async)?.Description }}" formControlName="Description"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Form model:

```js
this.projectEditForm = this._fb.group({
    Title: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]],
    Description: ['', [<any>Validators.required]]
});
```

Comment: add the code for the http call if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are not using the `FormControl` correctly. You should not bind to the `value` attribute of the `input` tag because it's `FormControl`'s job.

When binding to the `value` attribute, you are writing to the dom without notifying the `FormControl` that something has changed.

You should set the value dynamically using the `FormControl` instead. When you receive the data from http, you just need to call this :

```js
this.projectEditForm.get("controlName").setValue(randomValueFromSomewhere);
```

in your template (note that I removed the classes to be more concise):

```html
<div [formGroup]="projectEditForm">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="Title">
  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea formControlName="Description"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful and precise answer! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for the title input class is invalid

```
[class.validationError]="projectEditForm.controls.Name.invalid && (projectEditForm.controls.Description.dirty || submitted)"
```

It should be :

```
[class.validationError]="projectEditForm.controls.Title.invalid && (projectEditForm.controls.Title.dirty || submitted)"
```

Comment: That's right, I changed the names for the question, so in my code it's right sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try to init the form group on http call success and then:

```
this.projectEditForm = this._fb.group({
    Title: [project.ProjectName, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]],
    Description: [project.Description, [<any>Validators.required]]
});
```

Comment: creating the form on demand requires extra logic in the template (`*ngIf="projectEditForm"`) and does not sound like a good idea.